# Exchange Online - Share calendar external more than 6 months into the future

Tags: exchange, calendar

I want to share the calendar of an Exchange Online mailbox with both internal and external users. [I found](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/set-mailboxcalendarfolder?view=exchange-ps) the parameter `PublishDateRangeTo` and set it to `OneYear`. However, it works for internal users, but not for external users. Is there a known and documented limitation, or am I missing something?

The set parameter does not seem to work with external users. The shared calendar just shows 6 months into the future, not 12 months.

Comment: Are you using a shared calendar? Are you an administrator for your organization? Have you created a Microsoft 365 group for Outlook in order to share calendars?

Comment: I am the admin in this organisation. I do not want to create a 365 group. I want to share an user calendar with external users 12 months into the future.

Answer (score 0):

[Refer to the supported Sharing Scenarios here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FQCyn.png)

Firstly [creating a sharing policy](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/sharing/sharing-policies/create-a-sharing-policy) and [apply it to mailbox](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/sharing/sharing-policies/apply-a-sharing-policy) you want to share the calendar.

```
New-SharingPolicy -Name "Contoso" -Domains 'contoso.com: CalendarSharingFreeBusyDetail'

Set-Mailbox -Identity Barbara -SharingPolicy "Contoso"
```

Then users can share their calendar by sending an email invitation to the external user.